# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on sparkContext.parallelize() caused by JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to write some unit testing for my Apache Spark code. Below are my first simple try

```
public class SparkHelperTest {

    private JavaSparkContext sparkCtx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setMaster("local[2]");
        conf.setAppName("sparkHelperTest");
        sparkCtx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        nums.add(3);
        nums.add(4);
        nums.add(2);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sparkCtx.parallelize(nums,1);
        assertEquals(3, rdd.count());
    }
}
```

However, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.parallelize(JavaSparkContext.scala:143)
    at com.firsttry.SparkHelperTest.test(SparkHelperTest.java:39)
    ......
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.7
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    ... 29 more
```

As you can see from the error, it was caused by some depenencies conflicts. Below are some of my dependencies in the build.gradle:

```
compile (
            'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
            ......
)

testCompileOnly (
            'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1',
            'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1',
            'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.17.1',
            'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.17.1'
    )
```

I ran the dependencies check, and find the jackson 2.9.7 is coming from the dropWizard core as shown below

[image]

I tried the exclude thing and enforcing as below. It seems not working. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
compile (
                'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
                ......
    )
    
testCompileOnly (
                'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.17.1',
                'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.17.1',
                'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.17.1',
                'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.17.1'
) {
      exclude 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*:2.9.7'
      // also tried 
      // force = true 
}
```

Is there anyway I EXCLUDE this 2.9.7 version jackson for the unit test only?

Comment: Have ou tried this : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html

Comment: @HarryCoder, thanks for replying. I updated the post with what I tried and it was not working.